# How can I assign a variable to a list item in Python?

Tags: list, variables, python-3.x, variable-assignment, listitem

Is there a way I can assign a variable to an integer and then use that variable as the position value / index for an object in a list? e.g.

```
starting_line == int(starting_line)
lines_to_search = file_lines[starting_lines:]
```

Python shows

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

when I try this. Is there a way to achieve this idea in Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you added an `s` to the `starting_line` on your 2nd line. On the first line, I assume that you're converting to an integer from some other type, and you need `=` for assignment (`==` is compare):

```
starting_line = int(starting_line_string)
lines_to_search = file_lines[starting_line:]
```

Comment: sadly that didnt fix it :''( still showing the same error.  lines_to_search = file_lines[starting_line:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: I just made one more update. Where do you get the starting_line from? Is file_lines in fact a list?

Comment: yup it gets converted into a list from a string using the split function

Comment: darn i have no clue why i even put == in there changing it to = solved the problem. Thanks